# How to make a method that disables JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to make a method that disables `JButtons`.

The `JButtons` are in an array in the form of a grid, `JButton [int][int]` and the integers are supposed to be coordinates.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;


public class BS {

public static JFrame f = new JFrame("BS");



public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        initializeGui();
      }
    });

}

static void initializeGui() {

     JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,1));
//This is the array of the JButtons in the form of a grid
     final JButton[][] coordinates = new JButton[15][15];
     JPanel field;


    // set up the main GUI
    gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    field = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 15));

    field.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(15,15,15,15),new LineBorder(Color.BLACK)));

    JPanel boardConstrain = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    boardConstrain.add(field);
    gui.add(boardConstrain);

//The making of the grid
    for (int ii = 0; ii < coordinates.length; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < coordinates[ii].length; jj++) {
            JButton b = new JButton();

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                    new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
            b.setIcon(icon);

            coordinates[jj][ii] = b;
            field.add(coordinates[jj][ii]);
        }
    }

    f.add(gui);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);              
    f.pack();
    f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Call [`JButton#setEnabled(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled(boolean)) in the `JButton` you want to disable. Now for better help sooner post a proper [mcve] that shows your effort trying to solve the issue yourself

Comment: @Frakcool sorry for not posting the full code, the question sounded simple in my head for some reason :)

Comment: It's a simple problem, but in this site you must provide your code or else your code is taken as "too-broad". When are you trying to disable a `JButton`? When clicked?

Comment: @Frakcool When clicked would be more efficient if it is possible.But when clicked I would like for a given number of buttons following it to get disabled as well.

Comment: Explain yourself, what you mean by *"a given number of buttons following it to get disabled as well"* How many? Just the same row? Next row? Columns? How? Btw, using short names for class names or any other variable might be confusing in bigger programs (`BS` what does that mean?)

Comment: @Frakcool Let's say I press a button and a second one, all button between these two buttons are disabled. So that the user has the possibility to choose if it is a row or column (vertical or horizontal). Sorry if I am being unclear. I basically want to disable a column or row of buttons, but instead of doing one by one I just press the start button and end button of line of buttons I want to disable.

Comment: Ok, got it, let me try something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes in your code:

1. `public static JFrame f = new JFrame("BS");` `JFrame` shouldn't be `static` and should have a more meaningful name (like `frame` for example).
2. `final JButton[][] coordinates = new JButton[15][15];` moved this array as a class member and made it non final and also changed the name to `buttons` as it's easier to know what it is (`coordinates` to me, sounds more like an array of `Point` or `int`)

After that I added an `ActionListener`, see [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) tutorial.

```
private ActionListener listener = e -> {
    //Loops through the whole array in both dimensions
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(buttons[i][j])) { //Find the JButton that was clicked
                if (isStartButton) { //startButton is a boolean variable that tells us if this is the first button clicked or not
                    startXCoord = i;
                    startYCoord = j;
                } else {
                    endXCoord = i;
                    endYCoord = j;
                    disableButtons(); //Only when we have clicked twice we disable all the buttons in between
                }
                isStartButton = !isStartButton; //In every button click we change the value of this variable
                break; //No need to keep looking if we found our clicked button. Add another one with a condition to skip the outer loop.
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And a method called `disableButtons()` which disables all the buttons between the 2 clicked buttons:

```
private void disableButtons() {
    compareCoords(); //This method checks if first button clicked is after 2nd one.
    for (int i = startXCoord; i <= endXCoord; i++) {
        for (int j = startYCoord; j <= endYCoord; j++) {
            buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false); //We disable all buttons in between
        }
    }
}
```

At the end our code ends like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class DisableButtonsInBetween {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
    private JButton[][] buttons;

    private int startXCoord = -1;
    private int startYCoord = -1;
    private int endXCoord = -1;
    private int endYCoord = -1;
    private boolean isStartButton = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DisableButtonsInBetween().initializeGui();
            }
        });
    }

    void initializeGui() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 1));
        // This is the array of the JButtons in the form of a grid
        JPanel pane;
        buttons = new JButton[15][15];

        // set up the main GUI
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 15));

        pane.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15), new LineBorder(Color.BLACK)));

        JPanel boardConstrain = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        boardConstrain.add(pane);
        gui.add(boardConstrain);

        // The making of the grid
        for (int ii = 0; ii < buttons.length; ii++) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < buttons[ii].length; jj++) {
                buttons[jj][ii] = new JButton();

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
                buttons[jj][ii].setIcon(icon);
                buttons[jj][ii].addActionListener(listener);

                pane.add(buttons[jj][ii]);
            }
        }

        frame.add(gui);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //The ActionListener is what gets called when you click a JButton
    private ActionListener listener = e -> {
        //These for loops are done to identify which button was clicked.
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                if (e.getSource().equals(buttons[i][j])) {
                    if (isStartButton) {
                        //We save the coords of the 1st button clicked
                        startXCoord = i;
                        startYCoord = j;
                    } else {
                        //We save the coords of the 2nd button clicked and call the disableButtons method
                        endXCoord = i;
                        endYCoord = j;
                        disableButtons();
                    }
                    isStartButton = !isStartButton;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //This method disables all the buttons between the 2 that were clicked
    private void disableButtons() {
        compareCoords();
        for (int i = startXCoord; i <= endXCoord; i++) {
            for (int j = startYCoord; j <= endYCoord; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

    //This method compares the coords if the 2nd button was before (in its coords) than the 1st one it switched their coords
    private void compareCoords() {
        if (endXCoord < startXCoord) {
            int aux = startXCoord;
            startXCoord = endXCoord;
            endXCoord = aux;
        }
        if (endYCoord < startYCoord) {
            int aux = startYCoord;
            startYCoord = endYCoord;
            endYCoord = aux;
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

I hope this is what you were trying to do... if not please clarify.

> I do not have the arrow operator, " -> ". I think it requires a higher Java. Is there a way to replace this?

For Java 7 and lower use this for the `ActionListener`:

```
private ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                if (e.getSource().equals(buttons[i][j])) {
                    if (isStartButton) {
                        startXCoord = i;
                        startYCoord = j;
                    } else {
                        endXCoord = i;
                        endYCoord = j;
                        disableButtons();
                    }
                    isStartButton = !isStartButton;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I do not have the arrow operator, " -> ". I think it requires a higher Java. Is there a way to replace this?

Comment: I am getting the following error when the ActionListener is added:      
The type new ActionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

Comment: Did you added the 2 next lines? Like `@Override` and `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {` as I did in the edited code? Just copy-paste the whole `ActionListener` and it should be ok

Comment: I fixed it by importing `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` and removing the override

Comment: Would you mind adding some sort of comments above the methods, I am trying to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: What methods? I explained everything in the snippets above... What don't you understand?

Comment: I did try to explain what the methods do, I don't know if it helps but without knowing what you don't understand I can't really explain more

Comment: Never mind, I just needed to read through the code several times. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: If this answer solves your question be sure to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)